# Excel VBA On Error GoTo not Working

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

Please see my Sub below. If an error occurs whilst running the MyMacro Macro, it doesn't go to the ErrHandler and just behaves as the Default i.e. On Error Goto 0

```
Sub GoGoGo()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Application.Run "'MyFile.xlsm'!Module1.MyMacro"
    Msgbox("Success!")
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox ("Error")

End Sub
```

Is there a way around this?

Many thanks in advance to any help received :)

Comment: Put the error trap in *MyMacro*

Comment: MyMacro is a variable and could be a number of Macros, wanted to avoid this as I thought I could just put one main error handler in? It seems as if using Application.Run causes it to lose the Active Error Handler

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe? Im new to VBA but might work.

```
Sub GoGoGo()

On Error Resume Next

Application.Run "'MyFile.xlsm'!Module1.MyMacro"
Msgbox "Success!"
On Error goto 0
MsgBox "Error"

End Sub
```